# Expectation of CDF of standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics

How to calculate $E[\{\Phi(\alpha X)\}^{K}]$ for K being positive integer, $\Phi()$ is the CDF of standard normal distribution and $X\sim N(0,1)$. I tried using integration by part stuck.

Comment: What is the distribution of $x$ here?

Comment: You have not bothered to identify what the random variable is or its distribution and how this random variable relates to the _argument_ of $E\[\cdot]$. There is nothing random about $[\Phi(ax)]^K$ and so its expectation is just $[\Phi(ax)]^K$ regardless of what the random variable is.

Comment: See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43685/6633) on stats.SE for an approach that might suggest some possibilities.

Comment: Indeed, due to the invariance of the standard normal distribution by the rotations, this can be converted into the task of computing the surface of a given sector of the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^{K+1}$ (as I might have explained elsewhere on the site). Little hope of getting explicit formulas in general.

Comment: Any thought about the minimization of this expectation wrt to $0<\alpha<\infty$? What is the optimal value of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

In the case when $\alpha = 1$, the solution has an easy form:

$\Phi(X)$ is just the cdf of $X \sim N(0,1)$, which by the probability integral transform, has a standard Uniform distribution, so that the $\alpha = 1$ problem reduces to finding:

$$E[Z^k]  \quad \text{ where } Z \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$$

... to which the answer is: $\large \frac{1}{1+k}$ .

Comment: Not sure if this is true for $\alpha \neq 1$.

Comment: But $0<\alpha<\infty$.